# Как получить file_id у видео отправленного файлом в Telegram

Tags: python, telebot

Не получается забрать `File_id` у видео, отправленным файлом. Этот вариант работает, когда ты загрузил видео с телефона. Так же обычный метод, когда забираем `file_id`, работает лишь с документами по типу фото (когда фотку закидываешь в виде документа) - у видео не забирает. Кто что подскажет?

```py
import telebot

import requests

token = 'токен'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def repeat_all_message(message):
  print(message.text)
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message.text)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["document", "video", "audio"])
def handle_files(message):
  document_id = message.video.file_id
  file_info = bot.get_file(document_id)
  print(document_id) # Выводим file_id
  print(f'http://api.telegram.org/file/bot{token}/{file_info.file_path}') # Выводим ссылку на файл
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, document_id) # Отправляем пользователю file_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
  bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

К примеру, необходимо забрать `file_id` у этого видео: https://t.me/haikyuu_anime_all/110

Answer (score 0):

```
def handle_files(message):
    file_path = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id).file_path
    file_id = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id).file_id
    print(file_id)  # Выводим file_id
    print(f'http://api.telegram.org/file/bot{token}/{file_path}')  # Выводим ссылку на файл
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, file_id)  # Отправляем пользователю file_id
```

Надеюсь понял вас правильно, вопрос дан не совсем корректно